# How to make some data visible in all sections of a website with django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Am a newbie in Django and am developing my first website with this framework. Such website must have its social networks links at the top right of the screen along ALL sections. In order to accomplish that, I've made table in `models.py` with two fields: social network link, and fontawesome icon.

Each section of the website is rendered using a template, and all templates extend from only one base template. That base template is the one who must contains the social network links

The only way that I know how to show those links along ALL sections is passing them to the template in each view. That's against the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) rule. Is there a way to pass them only once, and make it visible to all website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Writing your own context processors`

There is only two rule is there...

1. Takes only one argument that is `request`
2. Must return dictionary

**context_processors.py**

```
def database_social_links(request):
    social_links = SocialLinks.objects.all()
    return {'social_links': social_links }
```

Update your settings.py to follow

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                'your_app.context_processors.database_social_links',
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And in your base.html or whatever...

```
{% for links in social_links %}
  {{ link.name }} {{ link.font_awesome }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raja! So you're saying I don't need to pass that data through "views.py"?

Comment: Yes that's right. See the custom context processors concept is to inject defined dictionary of data when your view executed without mentioning. So that will available in every templates.

Comment: But you are retrieving it from database so be careful with that scaling and all the things. Every page request this will get the values fro database, If you ask me I better avoid this. Instead I will use redis like database for better getting...:)

Comment: "redis"? sorry, am not familiarized with that term, what is it?

Comment: Better you start from [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+is+redis) and [django cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/) but not confuse with that now please focus get to work with your database level and later you can configure... Okay ?

Comment: okay, thanks again Raja! Good advice and kind help! regards! ^^